# ELMAH SQL tables and scripts not found

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, elmah, error-logging

I've a created an asp.net project and now I want to add ELMAH for logging purpose. When I searched for the ELMAH sql tables and scripts many sites show the link ::
https://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql But when I clicked the download link, it shows "*The requested URL /files/ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql was not found on this server*" .

Where can I get the required sql scripts for configuring ELMAH to use with SQL Server?
And are there any good tutorials from where I can know how can I implement ELMAH to my existing asp.net project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you used an old version, the repository was moved from code.google to [github](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah) and doesn't include ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql any longer. You can still find it [here](https://gist.github.com/5671024), but I'd recommend to get most recent version from github. See [ELMAH Tutorial](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/).

Comment: Good point. I'll make sure to update the ELMAH Tutorial which in fact reference the old script. The script is available directly in the ELMAH repository: https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/blob/master/src/Elmah.SqlServer/SQLServer.sql